# Should one light Shabbat candles if Friday is yom tov?

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, candle-lighting

Today is the second day of Rosh Hashana, and it happens to be Friday. The holiday will end after Shabbat begins. Should we light candles today?

Comment: Hello Nathan Fellman and welcome to Judaism.SE! Thanks for your clear question. It should quickly elicit well-sourced answers now that _shabas_ is over in most of the populated world. I might point out that Rosh Hashana most likely ended _simultaneous with_ the beginning of _shabas_ and not _after_ it.

Comment: @WAF, does starting Shabbat end Rosh Hashana?  I had assumed that for those 18 minutes it was both.

Comment: While the current answers certainly present the more common opinion, there are those who recommend against lighting Shabbat candles on YT (because of Hakhana IINM)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, we always light Shabbat candles, and at the usual time ([non-primary source](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=676)).  The only time a holiday affects candle-lighting is that on the second day of a two-day holiday, so long as the second day is not also Shabbat, you don't light the second-day candles until dark so as not to encroach the first day.

For Shabbat immediately after a holiday, or for the second day of a holiday, light the candles from a pre-existing flame (such as a pilot flame or long-burning candle lit before the holiday).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we should.

But I don't understand how can you ask this question on second day of Rosh Hashana. Using computer is forbidden on yom-tov.

Comment: Funny... it's like driving your car to synagogue for Saturday prayer.
However I do respect the candle-lighting ceremony itself from the traditional aspect tho.

Comment: For many people mitzvah observance develops over time.  I commend the OP for caring about Shabbat enough to ask the question.

Comment: The first part of this answer is unsourced, and the second part would be best expressed, if at all, as a comment on the question.

Comment: My family always drove to the synagogue on Saturday. Specifically, when I got married and my wife and I worked out Shabbat, we decided to light candles and to light them on time.  However, we still drive, use electricity and eat out on Shabbat (and Yom Tov, for that matter).